# How does the kernel set register cr3?

Tags: linux, x86, kernel

I understand that the mmu of the processor uses register `cr3` to translate linear addresses into physical ones, provided that `cr3` is properly set to the *physical address* of the page directory. But after the kernel has allocated the page tables, how would it find the *physical* address of the tables and set `cr3` to it?

EDIT: I'm talking about the linux kernel.

Comment: Well.. it created the tables so it knows where they are?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to assume that what's bugging you is this: assuming that (once switching to protected mode) the kernel only ever writes to virtual addresses, then this means that it writes the page tables it creates (e.g. for new processes) into virtual addresses. But since the kernel must put a *physical* address into `cr3`, then how can it convert the virtual address of the page tables into a physical one?

The short answer is basically what Margaret said: the page tables are found in kernel address space and the kernel keeps a close track of the virtual->physical mapping there.

To flesh this out a little bit more, Linux differentiates between two types of virtual addresses in the kernel:

- Kernel virtual addresses - which can map (conceptually) to any physical address; and
- Kernel logical addresses - which are virtual addresses that have a *linear* mapping to physical addresses

The kernel places the page tables in logical addresses, so you only need to focus on those for this discussion.

Mapping a logical address to its corresponding physical one requires only the subtraction of a constant (see e.g. the `__pa` macro in the Linux [source code](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.2/source/arch/ia64/include/asm/page.h#L59)).

For example, on x86, physical address 0 corresponds to logical address 0xC0000000, and physical address 0x8000 corresponds to logical address 0xC0008000.

So once the kernel places the page tables in a particular logical address, it can easily calculate which physical address it corresponds to.

For further details, you can read the relevant [Linux Device Drivers chapter](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1.shtml).